# How to have a program wait before running a specific line of code, too many threads problem

Tags: java

I'm creating a game and I have hit a roadblock. I want the platforms to drop one by one.

I looked at other questions on this site to help me, and I've
found a solution, when I run the code, however, the first three platforms drop, but after that my program crashes and I receive a warning.

```
public void move () throws Exception
{
    new java.util.Timer().schedule( 
        new java.util.TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                platform.move();
            }
        }, 
        0
    );
    new java.util.Timer().schedule( 
        new java.util.TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                platform2.move();
            }
        }, 
        1000
    );
    new java.util.Timer().schedule( 
        new java.util.TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                platform3.move();
            }
        }, 
        2000 //the program crashes now
    );
    new java.util.Timer().schedule( 
        new java.util.TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                platform4.move();
            }
        }, 
        3000
    );
    new java.util.Timer().schedule( 
        new java.util.TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                platform5.move();
            }
        }, 
        4000
```

For the first 3 platforms, the code works, then after the third platform, the code crashes and I receive the error message:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread

Any help would be appreciated as I am not that good at java.

Comment: You probably have some sort of game loop, where you can count the time manually. Then you can invoke the `move` functions of the platforms by hand. This would allow you an implementation without creating additional Threads.

Comment: in game development you don't move every element in its own thread, you move all elements in a single thread (in a single "tick") whereafter you render the game world

Comment: how do you do this, please?